# SCCM 2012 software updates failing

Tags: sccm-2012

Our SCCM setup stopped downloading updates 3 days ago.

The error shown on the wsyncmgr.log is this:

```
Sync failed: The subscription cannot be run at this time. Please wait a few minutes and try again. Source: Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.SoapExceptionProcessor.DeserializeAndThrow SMS_WSUS_SYNC_MANAGER   11/03/2014 02:53:05 p.m.    308 (0x0134)
```

Everything was running smoothly. I have tried to solve the issue but I'm stuck here.

EDIT: I have rebooted both DB and SCCM servers.

Comment: What does google say about the error? Minus this question of course.

Comment: @MDMoore313 nothing, actually.  Other than this question (and one posted by the same author elsewhere), this error message and source don't show up on the Googles.  Might be a case for MS support.

Comment: @hopelessN00b your google fu is weak grasshopper lipsync lipsync lipsync.. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/08fddd42-5160-4445-aefb-69cb546d3915/wsus-opens-and-then-shortly-gives-a-connection-error?forum=winserverwsus try rebooting the sql server.

Comment: @MDMoore313  Different source (`System.Web.Services`), and a DB reboot fixed the issue in that thread.... which has already been tried here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will schedule of both DB and SCCM servers again tonight. Otherwise, I'll have to open the case with MS. If the reboot works, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the question, I had rebooted the SQL server without success.

I opened a case with MS support and **the analyst recommended rebooting both SQL server and SCCM server.**

I tried this and the server is now syncing correctly with Windows Update.

The original cause of the issue was that the SQL server ran out of space. I did not have this information before. The space issue was fixed and the server rebooted, however, a reboot of both servers was necessary in this case.